# What is the relationship between the incident light and the light pass through a gas absorption in the form of electric field?

Tags: electric-fields

A beam of light pass through a gas absorption cell, a part of the light will be absorbed by the gas cell. According to Lambert-Beer's Law, $I_{out} =  I_{in}\cdot e^{-\alpha L} $. But this equation is in the form of intensity of light. I wondered what the relation would be between the incident light and the transmitted light given in the form of electric field. I know that $I = k\cdot E^{2}$ and $I$ is the intensity of the light, $E$ is the electric field strength of the light, $k$ is a constant. So, $E_{out} = E_{in}\cdot e^{-\alpha L \cdot 0.5}$?